# SCRAPY: Every time my spider crawls, it is scraping the same page (first page)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a code to scrape through a page using **Scrapy** in **Python**. Bellow I have pasted the *main.py* code. But, whenever I run my spider, ***it scrapes only from the first page*** ( DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe>), which is also the Referer in the Request Headers (when inspected).

I have tried adding the source of the "Request Payload" field data, which is pasted here: {"action":"loadList","skip":64,"filter":{"1005":[],"1006":[],"1007":[],"1009":[],"1013":[]}}, and when I try to open the page with it (modified in this lookout:

> https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe#32;'action':'loadList';'skip':'32';'sort':'none'

), the browser opens it. But the scrapy shell doesn't. I have also tried adding the numbers from the Request URL: https://www.tuscc.si/cache/script/tuscc.js?1563872492384, where the query string parameters are 1563872492384; but it still won't scrape from the requested page.

Also, I have tried many variations and added many stuff, all which i have read online just to see if there will be progress, but none....

The code is:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from tus_pomos.items import TusPomosItem
from tus_pomos.scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class TusPomosSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'TUSP'
    allowed_domains = ['www.tuscc.si']
    start_urls = ["https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe#0;1563872492384;",
                  "https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe#64;1563872492384;", ]
    download_delay = 5.0

    def start_requests(self):
        # payload = [
        #     {"action": "loadList",
        #      "skip": 0,
        #      "filter": {
        #          "1005": [],
        #          "1006": [],
        #          "1007": [],
        #          "1009": [],
        #          "1013": []}
        #      }]
        for url in self.start_urls:
            r = SplashRequest(url, self.parse, magic_response=False, dont_filter=True, endpoint='render.json', meta={
                'original_url': url,
                'dont_redirect': True},
                              args={
                                  'wait': 2,
                                  'html': 1
                              })
            r.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
            yield r

    def parse(self, response):
        items = TusPomosItem()
        pro = response.css(".thumb-box")
        for p in pro:
            pro_link = p.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first()
            pro_name = p.css(".description::text").extract_first()
            items['pro_link'] = pro_link
            items['pro_name'] = pro_name
            yield items
```

In conclusion, I am requesting to crawl all the pages from the pagination, for example this page (I also tried with command scrapy shell url):

> https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe#64;1563872492384;

But the response is always the first page, and it is scraping it repeatedly:

> https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe

I would be grateful if you help me. Thanks

---

THE PARSE_DETAILS GENERATOR FUNCTION

```
def parse_detail(self, response):
    items = TusPomosItem()
    pro = response.css(".thumb-box")
    for p in pro:
        pro_link = p.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first()
        pro_name = p.css(".description::text").extract_first()
        items['pro_link'] = pro_link
        items['pro_name'] = pro_name
        my_details = {
            'pro_link': pro_link,
            'pro_name': pro_name
        }
        with open('pro_file.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(my_details, json_file)

        yield items
        # yield scrapy.FormRequest(
        #     url='https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe',
        #     callback=self.parse_detail,
        #     method='POST',
        #     headers=self.headers
        #     )
```

Here I am not sure whether I should assign my „items“ variable the way it is, or get it from the response.body? 
Also, should the yield be the way it is, or should I change it with an Request(which is more than partially copied by the ANSWER code given)?

I am new here, so thanks for the understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Splash to render the pages, it's probably more efficient to get the data from the underlying requests that are made.
The below piece of code goes through all pages with articles. Under parse_detail, you can write the logic to load the data from the response into a json, in which you can find the 'pro_link' and 'pro_name' of the products.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from ..items import TusPomosItem


class TusPomosSpider(Spider):
    name = 'TUSP'
    allowed_domains = ['tuscc.si']
    start_urls = ["https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe"]
    download_delay = 5.0

    headers = {
        'Origin': 'https://www.tuscc.si',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        number_of_pages = int(response.xpath(
            '//*[@class="paginationHolder"]//@data-size').extract_first())
        number_per_page = int(response.xpath(
            '//*[@name="pageSize"]/*[@selected="selected"]/text()').extract_first())

        for page_number in range(0, number_of_pages):
            skip = number_per_page * page_number
            data = {"action": "loadList",
                    "filter": {"1005": [], "1006": [], "1007": [], "1009": [],
                               "1013": []},
                    "skip": str(skip),
                    "sort": "none"
                    }
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe',
                callback=self.parse_detail,
                method='POST',
                body=json.dumps(data),
                headers=self.headers
                )

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        detail_page = json.loads(response.text)
        for product in detail_page['docs']:
            item = TusPomosItem()
            item['pro_link'] = product['url']
            item['pro_name'] = product['title']
            yield item
```

Comment: This is a great xpath example for the pagination. I have Imported it, and wrote the parse details function. But the output I get is that the spider has just crawled, and doesn't scrape. Here it is

2019-07-23 16:13:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tuscc.si/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-07-23 16:13:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tuscc.si/produkti/instant-juhe> (referer: None)........................
After that, 8 more duplicates with referer with the url

Comment: Best edit your question with the parse_detail included or open a new question so we can check

Comment: I Will edit the question and in addition add the parse_detail

Comment: edited my response already to show how you can get the url & title of the products on the page, hope it helps

Comment: It helps, thank you very much. Meanwhile, if you are introduced, can you answer me, can I somehow get all the Request Payloads from the whole website?

Comment: Yes, you just need to write something that will first go through the main category links and then goes through the sub-categories. Payloads will probably be similar, maybe check if you need to make the 'filter' part dynamic